# Active window randomly minimizes

Tags: windows-7

I have a strange problem with my Windows 7 environment whereby an active window will suddenly minimize for no reason.

Here is an exact example:

1. Working on a Word doc, I decide I need to do a small calculation, and open 'Calculator'.
2. The Calculator window appears as active window, sitting on top with the Word doc visible behind.
3. As I am typing my figures into Calculator, it suddenly minimizes. The only way to get around this is to minimize all windows, then bring up Calculator.
4. If the mouse pointer is resting anywhere over window (e.g. Calculator), it will not minimize as described. Only when pthe ointer moves off the window. Behavior is therefore *as if* I am clicking on another window (when I'm not).

Note: This happens with other apps, not just calculator. That was just an example.

Comment: Are you on a laptop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Windows 7:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Go to "Ease of Access"
3. In the "Ease of Access Center" tab, click on "How your mouse works"
4. Click "Make the mouse easier to use"
5. In that and under "Make it easier to manage windows," uncheck the first option: "Activate the window by hovering"

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you !! I posted that question over 6 months ago.. and the problem has been happening for even longer. That answer worked perfectly. Yay !!